# How can I use PowerShell to enable NTFS compression, in place, on log files older than x days?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, ntfs, powershell-v4.0

I have an application server, running Windows 2012 R2, which generates a high volume of log files, to the point that it runs the application volume out of free space on a semi-regular basis.  Due to restrictions from the application itself, I can't move or rename the log files or enable NTFS data-deduplication, and due to it not being ten years ago anymore, I don't want to use a batch or vbscript to do this for me.

The log files are all in various subfolders of the application install directory, with different extensions (one component adds the date as the log file extension), and the application install directory has a space in it, because the application developers are malevolent.  The subfolders where the logs are written are exclusively used for the purpose of writing logs, at least.  This is also a heavily CPU-bound application, so I don't want to compress the log folders themselves and incur the CPU penalty associated with writing compressed files for the logs.

How can I use PowerShell to enable NTFS compression, in-place, on log files older than x days?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest solution, as PowerShell support for file operations is still rather lacking, is to create a PowerShell script to call the `compact.exe` utility and set it up as a scheduled task.  Because of the space in the path name, you want to call `compact.exe` directly, instead of using `Invoke-WMIMethod` and the `CIM_DataFile` class (which will cause a lot of extra effort to deal with the space in the path).

Assuming an age of 3 days for X, your PowerShell script would look something like:

```
$logfolder="[location of the first logging subfolder]"
$age=(get-date).AddDays(-3)

Get-ChildItem $logfolder | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -le $age -AND $_.Attributes -notlike "*Compressed*"} | 
ForEach-Object {
compact /C $_.FullName
}

$logfolder="[location of the next logging subfolder]"

Get-ChildItem $logfolder | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -le $age -AND $_.Attributes -notlike "*Compressed*"} | 
ForEach-Object {
compact /C $_.FullName
}

...
```

The second condition there is to speed up the script execution by skipping over already compressed files (which would be present after the first time this script was run).  If you wanted to, or had a lot of different logging subfolders, it would probably make sense to make a function out of that repeated PowerShell code, which would be a fairly trivial exercise.

Comment: challange--- -  can you write is as a reusable cmdlet with members and parameters? i nice script.

Comment: @Rob-d If I didn't have to work for a living, sure. :)  As I alluded to, doing it purely in PowerShell with Invoke-WMIMethod does not tolerate spaces in your path, and I _hate_ string tokenization as a programming task.  So a lot of effort, and not a lot of return, so that's not in danger of happening soon.

Comment: yep - the day job!, It's pretty slow this month so been on here a bit. - we could used the built in stuff for this Get-ChilidItem -filter *.log | where $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-3) | zip-file -compression optimal

Answer (score 6):

The repeated code can be avoided by using an array and a foreach loop:

```
$logfolders=("D:\Folder\One","D:\Folder\Two")
$age=(get-date).AddDays(-3)

foreach ($logfolder in $logfolders) {
    Get-ChildItem $logfolder | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -le $age -AND $_.Attributes -notlike "*Compressed*"} | 
    ForEach-Object {
    compact /C $_.FullName
    }
}
```

.....

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this without needing to rely on compact.exe, a "pure powershell" method by calling the NTFS compression directly. This handles spaces in file names and unicode filenames from Japan as well, the latter are difficult to supply to a compact.exe command line.
See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-fsctl_set_compression as well.

```txt
$MethodDefinition= @'
public static class FileTools
{
  private const int FSCTL_SET_COMPRESSION = 0x9C040;
  private const short COMPRESSION_FORMAT_DEFAULT = 1;
  private const short COMPRESSION_FORMAT_DISABLE = 0;

  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
  private static extern int DeviceIoControl(
      IntPtr hDevice,
      int dwIoControlCode,
      ref short lpInBuffer,
      int nInBufferSize,
      IntPtr lpOutBuffer,
      int nOutBufferSize,
      ref int lpBytesReturned,
      IntPtr lpOverlapped);

  public static bool Compact(IntPtr handle)
  {
    int lpBytesReturned = 0;
    short lpInBuffer = COMPRESSION_FORMAT_DEFAULT;

    return DeviceIoControl(handle, FSCTL_SET_COMPRESSION,
        ref lpInBuffer, sizeof(short), IntPtr.Zero, 0,
        ref lpBytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero) != 0;
  }
  public static bool Uncompact(IntPtr handle)
  {
    int lpBytesReturned = 0;
    short lpInBuffer = COMPRESSION_FORMAT_DISABLE;

    return DeviceIoControl(handle, FSCTL_SET_COMPRESSION,
        ref lpInBuffer, sizeof(short), IntPtr.Zero, 0,
        ref lpBytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero) != 0;
  }
}
'@

$Kernel32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodDefinition -Name ‘Kernel32’ -Namespace ‘Win32’ -PassThru

$logfilespec = "c:\Logfolder\*.log"

# compact anything older than three days
foreach ($File in (Get-ChildItem -Path $logfilespec -Recurse -File).Where({$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-3) -and $_.Attributes  -notmatch [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Compressed})) {
    $FileObject = [System.IO.File]::Open($File.FullName,'Open','ReadWrite','None')
    $Method = [Win32.Kernel32+FileTools]::Compact($FileObject.Handle)
    $FileObject.Close()
}

# decompact
foreach ($File in (Get-ChildItem -Path $logfilespec -Recurse -File).Where({$_.Attributes  -match [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Compressed})) {
    $FileObject = [System.IO.File]::Open($File.FullName,'Open','ReadWrite','None')
    $Method = [Win32.Kernel32+FileTools]::Uncompact($FileObject.Handle)
    $FileObject.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoke-WmiMethod -Path "Win32_Directory.Name='C:\FolderToCompress'" -Name compress

Comment: hows about the old `forfiles /m *. log /p path /d -7 /c "cmd /c compact @path"` or for folders would it be nearly the same

Answer (score -1):

If those log files are not on C: use the Server 2012 R2 deduplication feature. You can then configure it to only dedup .log files which are three days old (the default).
The second method to get this under control, or when it is on C: Move the log directory to a different drive and use a JUNCTION to point to the new place, easiest to create with Hardlink-Shell-Extension from https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html - and then use 2012 R2 deduplication on top.
I've see deduplication rates way above 90% on log files and the SQl-dump-for-backup drives.

Comment: Technically these are all potential alternatives, but so is "Turn off logging". I think it would be better as a comment on the OP, since it doesn't answer/address the question.

Comment: Tell this Serverfault. By the time of writing I did not have enough reputation to comment. There are quite some sites which expect their users to give them more priority above other things in life to make enough reputation just on their site to get normal functionality.

Comment: that does indeed complicate things, sorry for the frustration. I maintain my main point stands/is correct however: Alternative approaches are great as supplementary material, especially in a forum, but less-than-helpful at best in a Q/A / answering-a-specific-question format. (If you've never been on the opposite end of this, getting multiple irrelevant replies is quite frustrating)